# How to redirect IP address to localhost using kernel module

Tags: c, kernel-module, netfilter

I am learning programming of netfilter recently. I want to connect to the fake IP and port and redirect to the correct IP and port. but I don't want to use iptables.

### Information

Kernel Version : 4.15.0-132-generic

Ubuntu Version : 16

fake IP and port : 192.168.9.99:999

redirect IP and port : 192.168.9.4:80

test localhost IP and port : 127.0.0.1:19999

---

First, I use curl to test the above IP.

```
curl -I 192.168.9.99:999  # Connection timed out
curl -I 192.168.9.4:80    # HTTP/1.1 200 OK
curl -I 127.0.0.1:19999   # HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

---

I hook NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT and NF_INET_LOCAL_IN point. It works when I connect to the redirect IP via the fake IP.  I changed the redirect IP to localhost IP (127.0.0.1:19999). But it doesn't work. It modifies the IP at the NF_INET_LOCAL_IN point. But it did not respond, or even passed the NF_INET_LOCAL_IN point.

This is my code :

```
static void update_chksum(struct sk_buff *skb, struct iphdr *iph, struct tcphdr *tcp)
{
    iph->check = 0;
    iph->check = ip_fast_csum(iph,iph->ihl);

    tcp->check = 0;
    tcp->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(iph->saddr,
                                   iph->daddr,
                                   ntohs(iph->tot_len) - iph->ihl * 4,
                                   IPPROTO_TCP,
                                   csum_partial(tcp, ntohs(iph->tot_len) - iph->ihl * 4, 0));

    //checksum
    skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_NONE;
}



unsigned int hook_func(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{


    skb_linearize(skb);
    ip_header  = ip_hdr(skb);
    tcp_header = tcp_hdr(skb);

    unsigned int  fake_ip = inet_addr("192.168.9.99");
    unsigned int  fake_port = htons(999);
    unsigned int  redirect_ip = inet_addr("192.168.9.4");
    unsigned int  redirect_port = htons(80);
    
    //unsigned int  redirect_ip = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // failed to connect
    //unsigned int  redirect_port = htons(19999);


    if (state->hook == NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT) {
        if (ip_header->daddr == fake_ip && tcp_header->dest == fake_port) {
            ip_header->daddr = redirect_ip;
            tcp_header->dest = redirect_port;
            update_chksum(skb, ip_header, tcp_header);
        }
    }
    else if (state->hook == NF_INET_LOCAL_IN) {
        if (ip_header->saddr == redirect_ip && tcp_header->source == redirect_port) {
            ip_header->saddr = fake_ip;
            tcp_header->source = fake_port;
            update_chksum(skb, ip_header, tcp_header);

        }
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

I searched for related information and the answer I got was to enable this option in the kernel. But it still doesn't work.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

result:

test1 : 192.168.9.99:999 ---> 192.168.9.4:80   // connection succeeded

test2 : 192.168.9.99:999 ---> 127.0.0.1:19999  // connection failed

So my question : How to redirect to localhost ?

Comment: Can someone give me some inspiration?